# PDFKit JS image grows bigger when placed in PDF

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing, node-pdfkit

I have an image (a strange image, but the marks in the corner just help me determine where the corners are):

[image: here]

However when I create a PDF using PDFKit, I get this (a print preview of the A5 PDF it generates):

[image: this]

The image is originally from a HTML canvas (w: 1000px, h: 709px), I do the following:

```
    const canvasImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
```

and send it to the backend. In the backend I do this:

```
        const pdfDoc = new PDFDocument({
          // autoFirstPage: false,
          layout: 'landscape',
          size: 'a5'
        });

        // const img = pdfDoc.openImage(base64Image);
        // pdfDoc.addPage({size: [img.width, img.height]});
        pdfDoc.image(base64Image, 0, 0, {align: 'center', width: 2480, height: 1748});
        pdfDoc.pipe(awsUpload(`order-${orderNumber}.pdf`));
        pdfDoc.end();
```

I have tried all sorts of variations on the image size, but it always makes it much much bigger than the A5 itself.

I have even tried converting it to 300dpi on the frontend using shuttershock's changeDPI function

```
    const canvasImage = canvas.current.toDataURL('image/png');
    const canvasImage300Dpi = changeDpiDataUrl(canvasImage, 300);
```

Still no luck :(.

How do I get the dimensions of the image to fit within the A5 pdf?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a hardcoded image size.
Use your A5 size [419.53, 595.28] as your image width. In your case I would say: 595.28
Don't use height to scale proportional.